# Parse rendered HTML for CSS property value in Python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, phantomjs

I am currently using **Selenium** and **PhantomJS** with Python to crawl *rendered web pages*. It is easy to check if some word is present in the HTML content (ex. `if "example" in html`...), but I am interested in searching the pages for elements containing a CSS property with a value that is greater than or equal to something.

For example, it would be ideal to crawl a list of sites and save the pages that have CSS giving an element a z-index an abnormally large value. Everything is built, except for the CSS crawling functionality for the rendered pages. Does anyone have any advice for tackling this?

Comment: Doesn't PhantomJS allow you to: `window.getComputedStyle(elmt)`? See here: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html.  *It is easy to check if some word is present in the HTML content (ex. if "example" in html...)* Is it hard to check what number a string contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- For html5 (default is UTF-8) -->
  <meta charaset="UTF-8">
  <title>Phantom JS Example</title>

  <style>
    img#red {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100px;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 5;    #***z-index set by CSS****
    }

    img#black {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100px;
      top: 100px;
      z-index: 2;    #***z-index set by CSS****
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Hello</div>

  <img src="4row_red.png" id="red" width="40" height="40">
  <img src="4row_black.png" id="black" width="40" height="40">

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var red = document.getElementById('red');
  red.style.zIndex = "0";    #****z-idex set by JAVASCRIPT****
};
</script>
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550) #For bug
driver.get("http://localhost:8000")

png = driver.find_element_by_id('red')
#print png.css_value('zIndex')  <--AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'css_value'
print "{} id={}-> {}".format(
    png.tag_name,
    png.get_attribute('id'),
    png.value_of_css_property('zIndex')
)
#print png.style('zIndex')  <--AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'style'
print "get_attribute('zIndex') -> {}".format(
    png.get_attribute('zIndex')
)

print '-' * 20

imgs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for img in imgs:
    print "{} id={}-> {}".format(
        img.tag_name,
        img.get_attribute('id'),
        img.value_of_css_property('zIndex')
    )

print "get_attribute('zIndex') -> {}".format(
    imgs[-1].get_attribute('zIndex')
)

print '-' * 20

all_tags = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('*')

for tag in all_tags:
    print "{} --> {}".format(
            tag.tag_name,
            tag.value_of_css_property('zIndex')
    )

driver.quit()


--output:--
img id=red-> 1    #Found the z-index set by the js.
get_attribute('zIndex') -> None  #Didn't find the z-index set by the js
--------------------
img id=red-> 1
img id=black-> 3  #Found the z-index set by the css stylesheet
get_attribute('zIndex') -> None  #Didn't find the z-index set by the css stylesheet
--------------------
html --> 0
head --> auto
meta --> auto
title --> auto
style --> auto
body --> auto
div --> auto
img --> 1
img --> 3
script --> auto
```

Setup:

```
$ pip install selenium
$ brew install phantomjs
```

https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/

**value_of_css_property(property_name):**
Returns the value of a CSS property

**get_attribute(name):**
Gets the given attribute or property of the element.

This method will return the value of the given property if this is set, otherwise it returns the value of the attribute with the same name if that exists, or None.

Values which are considered truthy, that is equals “true” or “false”, are returned as booleans. All other non-None values are returned as strings. For attributes or properties which does not exist, None is returned.

Args:
name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property

Not very good docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at it without seeing your code.  [Here're the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) -- which it sounds like you've already read.

```
css_items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(tag.selector)
# use a list comprehension to test if element meets your criterion
desired_elems = [item for item in css_items if item.get_attribute(property) >= abnormally_large_value]
if len(desired_elems):
     pass # do some code stuff
```

Here are the [docs for the `get_attribute()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

I hope that answer helps some.  Obvi you'd need to post a snippet for a more complete analysis.  Best of luck!